# Get max date and exact previous from max date from a given date range sql server

Tags: sql, datetime

I have date column in table

ColumnName: event_timestamp 
2015-06-01 15:23:31.000
2015-06-01 15:25:21.000
2015-06-03 09:00:41.000
2015-06-03 09:14:49.000
2015-06-03 09:15:03.000
2015-06-03 09:15:23.000
2015-06-06 08:40:06.000
2015-06-06 08:40:19.000
2015-06-06 11:13:35.000
2015-06-06 11:13:53.000
2015-06-06 11:15:04.000
2015-06-06 11:15:30.000
2015-06-09 15:08:13.000
2015-06-09 15:08:33.000
2015-06-09 15:08:45.000
2015-06-09 15:09:05.000

I want only 
2015-06-01
2015-06-03
2015-06-06
2015-06-09

AND 
2015-06-06   in one column
2015-06-09   in other column

AND also same column 
2015-06-06 
2015-06-09

I tried:

```
    SELECT CONVERT(datetime,MAX(myDate),103), (MAX(CONVERT(datetime,mydate,103)))-1 as DT 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT (CONVERT(VARCHAR,events.event_timestamp, 103)) myDate
FROM events where event_timestamp Between '01-Jun-15 11:14:40 AM' AND '11-Jun-15 11:14:40 AM'
) tbl
```

but cannot access

2015-06-06   in one column
2015-06-09   in other column

Comment: What do you mean by "2015-06-06 in one column
2015-06-09 in other column"?  Your sample code doesn't generate two columns.

Comment: Perhaps show the desired result from you sample data with all rows and columns.

Comment: SELECT MAX(myDate), (MAX(CONVERT(datetime,mydate,101))-1) as DT 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT (CONVERT(VARCHAR,events.event_timestamp, 103)) myDate
FROM events where event_timestamp Between '01-Jun-15 11:14:40 AM' AND '11-Jun-15 11:14:40 AM'
) tbl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using sql server

```
WITH cteEvents AS 
(
    SELECT
        CONVERT(VARCHAR,event_timestamp,101) event_date,
        RANK()OVER(ORDER BY CONVERT(VARCHAR,event_timestamp,101) DESC) rnk

    FROM
        events
    WHERE
        event_timestamp BETWEEN '01-Jun-15 11:14:40 AM'
                            AND     '11-Jun-15 11:14:40 AM'
    GROUP BY 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR,event_timestamp,101)
)
SELECT 
    event_date, 
    (SELECT event_date FROM cteEvents WHERE rnk = 2),  
    (SELECT event_date FROM cteEvents WHERE rnk = 1) 
FROM 
    cteEvents
```

Answer (score 1):

Stick with ISO-standard date formats and built-in types:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(DATE, e.event_timestamp) myDate
FROM events e
WHERE e.event_timestamp Between '2015-06-01T11:14:40' AND '2015-06-11T11:14:40'
```

This will probably fix your problem.

Comment: how to access only 
2015-06-06 ,
2015-06-09

Answer (score 0):

Thanks (user1221684), THIS WORK FINE,

```
WITH cteEvents AS 
(
    SELECT
        CONVERT(VARCHAR,event_timestamp,103) event_date,
        RANK()OVER(ORDER BY CONVERT(VARCHAR,event_timestamp,103) DESC) rnk
    FROM
        events
    WHERE
        event_timestamp BETWEEN '01-Jun-15 11:14:40 AM'
                            AND     '11-Jun-15 11:14:40 AM'
    GROUP BY 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR,event_timestamp,103)
)
SELECT 
    max(event_date), 
    (SELECT event_date FROM cteEvents WHERE rnk = 2)
    --,(SELECT event_date FROM cteEvents WHERE rnk = 1) 
FROM 
    cteEvents
```

also this work fine

```
SELECT top 2 myDate
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT (CONVERT(VARCHAR,events.event_timestamp, 103)) myDate
FROM events where event_timestamp Between '01-Jun-15 11:14:40 AM' AND '11-Jun-15 11:14:40 AM'
) tbl
order by myDate desc
```